# Serve .ICS files as binaries purely through .htaccess or apache conf

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

When I upload an .ICS file to the server and try to download it, it appears as text.  I would like the "Save as" dialog to appear so that the user can open the file as a binary in Outlook.

What can I put into the apache conf or .htaccess rule to make the headers for ICS files work like a binary.  Example: A .doc file opens like a binary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to add the following line to your .htaccess file:

AddType text/calendar .ics

Comment: Perfect.  Worked like a charm!